# Almost Perfect Kattis (Time Limit Exceeded )

Tags: python

Hope you can help me in this problem :

So the problem is Almost Perfect in Kattis.

https://open.kattis.com/problems/almostperfect

This is my code. the first test is passed but the second no it gives me am message (Time Limit Exceeded)

```
def isperfect(n):

l=0
for i in range(1,n):
    if n%i==0:
        l+=i
    if l>n+2 :
        print(f"{n} not perfect")
        break
    
if(l==n):
    print(f"{n} perfect")
elif abs((n-l))<=2:
    print(f"{n} almost perfect")
else :
    print(f"{n} not perfect")
    

while True:


try :
    n = int(input())
    isperfect(n)
except EOFError:
    break;
```

Where is the mistake ? or how can I optimise it ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: The problem is behind a login on an external link that could rot. Can you give a synopsis of what this code is supposed to do as an edit to the question? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any description of the algorithm _in the question itself_ after the edit, just a link that can go down over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the code is simply too slow. Luckily, there's a simple optimization that can save you.

Note that if `d` is a divisor of `n`, then `n / d` is also a divisor. Furthermore, if `d` is lesser than `sqrt(n)`, then `n / d` is greater than `sqrt(n)` (and vice-versa).

What this effectively means is we only need to check numbers up to `sqrt(n)` instead of checking all the way to `n`. And for every divisor `d` we find, we also make sure to add `n / d` to the divisor sum, except when `d` is `1` or exactly `sqrt(n)`.

Here's what that might look like in your code:

```py
    l = 1
    for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            l += i
            if i < sqrt(n): l += n // i
        if l > n + 2: break
```

Another minor bug is that when `l > n + 2` you'll print the message twice, which is easily solved by removing the `print` before `break`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import math
def almostPerfect(num):

    count = 1
    for i in range (2,int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1):
        if(num % i == 0):
            count += i
            if(i*i != num):
                count += num // i

    if(count == num):
        return "{} perfect".format(num)
    elif (count == (num-2)):
        return "{} almost perfect".format(num)
    elif (count == (num+2)):
        return "{} almost perfect".format(num)
    elif (count == (num-1)):
        return "{} almost perfect".format(num)
    elif (count == (num+1)):
        return "{} almost perfect".format(num)
    else:
        return "{} not perfect".format(num)

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    line = int(line)
    print(almostPerfect(line))
```

This could be another solution that works for python, and I think we need to take note about `(i*i != num)`, so that we don't start adding the same number.